# Auto login in Umbraco Site with Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, umbraco, umbraco7, autologin

I am trying to implement auto login in Umbracro site with Active Directory users. Can any one explain how would I do that? I have been trying to implement this feature for a while and ended up having a solution where I can authenticate user from Active Directory but User must be present in Umbraco CMS otherwise it won't work. I want to have auto login features and if the user is not in umbraco CMS it should create automatically. I have implemented OwinStartup and UserManager class.
I have override CheckPasswordAsync method in UserManager class but Umbraco does not hit this action if the user is not exist in Umbraco CMS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!